# cursor alignment in textbox

Tags: css, internet-explorer, forms

I have a form which looks exactly the way i want in every browser except for IE.  I have been having a difficult time figuring out what adjustment I need to make to the css to make it look right in IE (and still look right in all of the other main browsers)

My HTML is:

```
        <td valign="top" align="left">

        <form name="postcode" action="plans.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="c" size=1 class="postcode" onKeyup="autotab(this, document.postcode.o)" maxlength=1> 
        <input type="text" name="o" size=1 class="postcode" onKeyup="autotab(this, document.postcode.d)" maxlength=1> 
        <input type="text" name="d" size=1 class="postcode" onKeyup="autotab(this, document.postcode.e)" maxlength=1>
        <input type="text" name="e" size=1 class="postcode" maxlength=1>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        then choose...<br/><br/>
        <input name="electricity" type="checkbox" value="electricity" />electricity
        <br/>
        <input name="gas" type="checkbox"  value="gas" />gas
        <br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <input type="image" src="images/billCompare-view-plans.gif" value ="show plans" >
          </p>
        </form>
    </td>
```

and my css is:

```
    @charset "UTF-8";
    /* CSS Document */
    body { 
        font-size:14px;
        font-family:"Century Gothic";
    }

    .table_header{
        font-size:18px;
        font-family:"Century Gothic";
        color:#FFF;
    }

    .body_text{
        text-align:justify;
    }

    .menu{ 
        text-align:right;
        vertical-align:bottom;
    }

    .postcode{
            border-style:double;
            font-size:20px;
            border-color:#F60;
            text-align:center;
            vertical-align:middle;
            height:70px;
    }

    input.checkbox{
    height:40px; 
        width: 40px;
    } 

    form p label { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;}
```

The cursor on all other browsers is aligned in the center and middle of the boxes(which is what i want).  but for some reason in IE in aligned center and to the top.

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Just had this issue. What worked for me was using line-height.

Try adding line-height: 70px to .postcode

Comment: I set up a page to reproduce this, but hadn't solved it. When I add that it's OK for IE, but on Chrome the cursor fills the whole box vertically. When you type something it changes size to fill the top half of the box. This may not be  a problem for freddy6.

Comment: That is very interesting. I'm having the same issue as well. I might have to experiment with padding instead of using line-height and see if I can get better results.

Comment: line-height: 175% and text-indent: 5px worked for my particular situation...looks good in both Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer. IE was aligning the cursor position of the text box at the top whereas Firefox was fine - so both css rules work good in both browsers now

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the input `line height` with a percentage: `line-height: 140%;`.

The percentage valor will align Placeholder and input text.